# (Closed) BindingSource detecting changes issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource, sqldataadapter

I had a task to bind two *DataGridView*'s, main problem I can't see the changes when I cast *BindingSource* data source to *DataSet* (I need this for *SqlDataAdapter*).

I can workaround this by deleting db table contents, but this is not suitable for me.

I could catch these events, but I need to update DB on disposing the Form.

```
var bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
var set = (DataSet)bs.DataSource; //here DataSet HasChanges() method always returns true
```

And when I use Tables from *DataSet* in *SqlDataAdapter* Update() and Fill() methods do the Insert for me, because values are always shown as new.

It is kind of though to explain it right, I hope I have succeeded.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Fixed it by initializing *DataSet* on class level and adding AcceptChanges method.
Also removed casting from *BindingSource*.

Code snippet for initialization of *DataSet*:

```
dataSetT = new DataSet();
            dataSetT.ReadXmlSchema(xmlSchemeFile);
            dataSetT.ReadXml(populateDataSet == null ? xmlSchemeFile : xmlDataFile, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);

            var autoSource = new BindingSource();
            var repairSource = new BindingSource();

            autoSource.DataSource = dataSetT;
            autoSource.DataMember = "Auto";
            repairSource.DataSource = autoSource;
            repairSource.DataMember = "VIN_FK";

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = autoSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = repairSource;
            dataSetT.AcceptChanges();
```

With AcceptChanges method now dataSetT.HasChanges() returns a realistic value. And then I use *DataAdapter* Update method.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my question, description is in edited question.
Thanks.